# Convert string to DateTime without changing the original string 's format c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datetime, datetime-format

I am reading date-time from MySQL database table kept on server to get current sever date-time using query "Select Now()".I get the date-time.

```
var tmpString = DateTime.Parse(reader[0].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
DateTime result = Convert.ToDateTime(tmpString);
```

reader[0] contains my server's current date time.
tmpString has  value "2017-04-06 03:10:20 PM"

result contains date-time in the following format : 
06-Apr-17 3:10:20 PM (My machine's date-time format)

But I want date-time as per my servers date-time format ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")

I've tried using

```
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(tmpString, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

which also returns
06-Apr-17 3:16:11 PM.

Comment: Is `reader[0]` a DateTime in the database?  If so, then why convert to `string` only to convert it _back_ to `DateTime`?

Comment: Yes `reader[0]` is `DateTime` object, but i want `DateTime` in this format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt`

Comment: `DateTime` _has no format_!  Converting from `string` to `DateTime` and back to `string` will not accomplish anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help full

```
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);

        customCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt";

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = customCulture;

        DateTime newDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt"));
```

Comment: it returns result as 01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM. Not working as expected.

Comment: I edited one line
`customCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";`
Then it worked properly.
your code was 99% correct but it was repeating time part twice.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the point of converting `DateTime.Now` to string only to then convert it back to `DateTime`?  That makes no sense.

Comment: DateTime.Now will give you the result of system date format using .ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt") just changing the format of the date what we want and again convert it to DateTime,Because of it culture changed ( customCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt";) we will get the correct format.

Comment: `DateTime` _has no format_!  Converting from `DateTime` to `string` and back to `DateTime` accomplishes nothing.  This code is just a waste of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly as follows:

result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss")

This should work.

Comment: This will return string, I want result of type DateTime.